# pdflatex+ biblatex + biber and special characters produce error

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, biber

**EDIT: The Post has been updated considering the first 19 comments**

In my LaTeX document

```
 \href{en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9lude_%C3%A0_l'apr%C3%A8s-midi_d'un_faune}{en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prélude\_à\_l'après-midi\_d'un\_faune}
```

works perfectly and produces a correct link. 
I want to use that link in my `.bib` file too, but I can't get it working. Alone the presence of

```
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9lude_%C3%A0_l'apr%C3%A8s-midi_d'un_faune
```

is enough to produce an error when compiling with `biber`. 
I don't know where to search for the error. I thought `biblatex` in combination with `biber` is capable of `utf8`, so this should not be a problem at all, right?

So I have prepared two example files, which do not work on my system (Ubuntu 13.04):
Please consider:

#### `bibfile.bib`:

```
@misc{wiki3,
author = {Wikipedia},
title = {Prélude à l’après-midi d’un faune},
howpublished = {\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9lude_%C3%A0_l'apr%C3%A8s-midi_d'un_faune}{en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prélude\_à\_l'après-midi\_d'un\_faune}},
note = "[Zugriff am 12. Mai 2013 um 19:35]"
}
```

#### `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
EXAMPLE CONTENT
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex test.tex` is successful.
Running `biber test` produces:

```
INFO - This is Biber 0.9.9
INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing bib section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'bibfile.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Finished Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bibfile.bib'
INFO - Sorting list 'MAIN' keys
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en_US.UTF-8'
INFO - Sorting list 'SHORTHANDS' keys
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en_US.UTF-8'
INFO - Writing 'test.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to test.bbl
```

Rerunning `pdflatex test.tex` outputs (with pressing ENTER a couple times in between):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation,         lo
aded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx) (./test.aux)     (./test.bbl)

Runaway argument?
{\href {en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr\field {note}{[Zugriff am 12. Mai 201\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \field.
<inserted text>
            \par
l.7 \begin{document}

?
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@bbl@data

l.7 \begin{document}

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
               \xdef
l.7 \begin{document}

?
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
               \xdef
l.7 \begin{document}

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
               \xdef
l.7 \begin{document}

?
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@bbl@data

l.7 \begin{document}

?
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@bbl@data

l.7 \begin{document}

?
! You can't use `\xdef' after \advance.
<argument> \xdef
             \csname\endcsname{\expandonce \csname\endcsname\csname c@1\...
l.7 \begin{document}

?
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@bbl@data

l.133 \newcounter{section@level}

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
               \xdef
l.133 \newcounter{section@level}

?
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
               \xdef
l.133 \newcounter{section@level}

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
               \xdef
l.133 \newcounter{section@level}

?
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@bbl@data

l.133 \newcounter{section@level}

?
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@bbl@data

l.133 \newcounter{section@level}

?
! You can't use `\xdef' after \advance.
<argument> \xdef
             \csname\endcsname{\expandonce \csname\endcsname\csname c@1\...
l.133 \newcounter{section@level}

?
) (./test.out) (./test.out)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@bbl@data

l.7 \begin{document}

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
               \xdef
l.7 \begin{document}

?
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
               \xdef
l.7 \begin{document}

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
               \xdef
l.7 \begin{document}

?
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@bbl@data

l.7 \begin{document}

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
               \xdef
l.7 \begin{document}

?
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@bbl@data

l.7 \begin{document}

?
! You can't use `\xdef' after \advance.
<argument> \xdef
             \csname\endcsname{\expandonce \csname\endcsname\csname c@1\...
l.7 \begin{document}

?
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
}] (./test.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `test.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.


LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
(\end occurred inside a group at level 2)

### semi simple group (level 2) entered at line 7 (\begingroup)
### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 7 (\begingroup)
### bottom level </home/user/.texmf-        var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecrm1000.60
0pk>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 6365 bytes).
```

No reference is produced.

My aim is to have an entry like:

```
@misc{wiki3,
author = {Wikipedia},
title = {Prélude à l’après-midi d’un faune},
howpublished = {\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9lude_%C3%A0_l'apr%C3%A8s-midi_d'un_faune}{en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prélude\_à\_l'après-midi\_d'un\_faune}},
note = "[Zugriff am 12. Mai 2013 um 19:35]"
}
```

in my `bibfile.bib`.

I would very very glad if someone could help me, as I have tried everything that came to my mind with no solution.
Maybe my code works for you and my installation is broken?

**EDIT 2:**
A bug was discovered and reported during looking in this problem:
https://sourceforge.net/p/biblatex-biber/bugs/144/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: ...As a quick fix, use '\' before the percentage sign.

Comment: @MarioS.E. Does not work :(

Comment: you have to write \ before every %.  This is not the right approach (I'm also waiting for the answer), but does work.

Comment: I did it, and it did not work for me :(

Comment: You also have to change à for \`{a} and è for \`{e}

Comment: funny ... where is the utf8 support then?

Comment: That's why I know this is not the correct answer :)

Comment: Have you used `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` ?

Comment: btw: à for `{a} and è for `{e} do not change anything, because they are not related to the problem (the problem is only "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9lude_%C3%A0_l'apr%C3%A8s-midi_d'un_faune}{en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prélude\_à\_l'après-midi\_d'un\_faune"
If I leave out this line, everything is fine.

Comment: "Have you used \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} ?" yes

Comment: Actually, adding those lines does change the error messages, but still I am getting errors.

Comment: As you can see in your error log, You are asking for UTF8 ("No sort tailoring available for locale 'en_US.UTF-8"), but it is not available, and then it is digested as ASCII ("Writing 'test.bbl' with encoding 'ascii'").  That's why if you use \ before every %, _ and change the accents as described [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) you'll get the right output

Comment: I am getting "INFO - Writing 'test.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'"
Should I repost the actual errors?

Comment: Yes, update your answer to the latest configuration please.  I'm no `biblatex` expert, but I'm sure you'll get an answer in no time :)

Comment: Okay, I have changed all files:
test.tex: http://pastebin.com/VbpCJ3Ca
bibfile.bib: http://pastebin.com/hNs3PdaN
output of "biber test": http://pastebin.com/VH4uguME
output of "pdflatex test.tex": http://pastebin.com/VH4uguME
(after pressing ENTER a couple of times)
I am sorry this is getting messy now, but I don't have the rights to edit my message :(

Comment: The output of `pdflatex test.tex` link is the same as `biber test`...

Comment: strange ... sry ... here is the output: http://pastebin.com/6TUS4zhe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you did not insert `http://` inside `\href` in your `.bib` file, together with the fact that you have to insert `\` before each `%`.

Try to modify it in this way, it seems to work for me:

```
@misc{wiki3,
author = {Wikipedia},
title = {Prélude à l’après-midi d’un faune},
howpublished = {\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr\%C3\%A9lude_\%C3\%A0_l'apr\%C3\%A8s-midi_d'un_faune}{en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prélude\_à\_l'après-midi\_d'un\_faune}},
note = "[Zugriff am 12. Mai 2013 um 19:35]"
}
```

---

**ADDENDUM**

This is just a suggestion.

When your bibliography item is an online resource, the `online` entry can be used instead of `misc`.

You can then substitute

```
@misc{wiki3,
```

with

```
@online{wiki3,
```

and

```
howpublished = {\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr\%C3\%A9lude_\%C3\%A0_l'apr\%C3\%A8s-midi_d'un_faune}{en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prélude\_à\_l'après-midi\_d'un\_faune}},
```

with

```
url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prélude_à_l'après-midi_d'un_faune},
```

Note that, in any case, the field `url` can be used inside any entry type, `misc` included.

Comment: It does not work for me :(. I left out http:// because I did not have the rights to post more than two urls, so I had to remove it.

Comment: I've also added `\ ` before each `%`. Did you try it as I've  written?

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with my texlive install? 
It would really help me if sb. could confirm the code compiles without errors for them.

Comment: okay ... it seems to work ... I tried your answer again and it worked :)

Comment: thank you very much sir! thank you for your help, everybody!

Comment: remains odd though that you need \ despite utf8 support though

Comment: @GEO -- the escaping of `%` and `_` have nothing to do with UTF-8.